# Get an array of strings separating a string on N character incrementally

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I asked a question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43742356/1096637), and even though I placed it in the wrong place (it should have been here), [Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543207/redu) was nice enough to give me a nice answer to my question.

Here is the original question for reference:

given the following input:

```
"/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"
```

I would like to end up with:

```
[
    "/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels", 
    "/bob/ross/is/awesome", 
    "/bob/ross/is", 
    "/bob/ross", 
    "/bob"
]
```

The answer that Redu was nice enough to post was as follows:

```
res = s => s.length ? [s].concat(res(s.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0])) : [];
```

However he also commented the following:

> I honestly wouldn't advise recursion in JS, however since you have asked for it, i have provided a recursive answer down below.

Which makes me wonder, is there a better way to do this without recursion, but just as succinctly?

My original non-recursive function is as follows:

```js
getWords = function( string ){

    // Get an array of all words in the provided string separating on "/"
    let words = string.split("/");

    // Filter out empty strings from leading/trailing "/" characters
    words = words.filter( function(a){return a !== ""} );

    // Create an array to store results in
    let results = [];

    // Create an iteration for each word in the array
    for (var i=0, j=words.length; i<j; i++){

        // Create a string to concatenate to
        let result = "";

        // Loop over each word in the array minus the current iteration of "i"
        for (var k=0, l=words.length - i; k<l; k++){

            // Contatenate using the special character plus the current word
            result += "/" + words[k];
        }

        // Push the resulting string to the results array
        results.push(result);
    }
    
    // Set the results to display
    resultsDisplay.innerHTML = results.toString().replace(/,/g, " -- ");

    // Return the results array
    return results;
}

input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
resultsDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName("results")[0];
input.addEventListener("input", function(){
getWords(input.value)
});
getWords(input.value);
```

```html
<input value="bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels" />
<p class="results"></p>
```

This code is, admittedly, awful, hence my original post.

Comment: Why does your `<input>`'s  value `"bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"` not have a leading slash?

Comment: To prove you get a leading slash regardless of whether or not there is one in the input string, which is important to my uses.

Comment: However, Redu's answer relies on the input having a leading slash. You might want to make that requirement more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which makes me wonder, is there a better way to do this without
>   recursion, but just as succinctly?

Recursion can be an issue if your input size is huge and you recurse often and your JavaScript engine can't perform [tail call optimization](http://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/). Due to limited call stack size, you might then encounter a [Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570551/call-stack-size-in-recursive-functions-maximum-call-stack-size-is-lower-than-ex) error. You might also want to avoid recursion if performance is a concern, as the function call overhead is not marginal in JavaScript.

**So, how do you eliminate the recursion?**

First of all, in order to gain a clear understanding of [Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543207/redu)'s minified one-liner:

```
res = s => s.length ? [s].concat(res(s.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0])) : [];
```

I recommend to rewrite it into a self-documenting but otherwise equivalent function:

```
function expand(path) {
  if (path.length == 0) return [];
  let result = [path];

  path = path.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0];
  result = result.concat(expand(path));

  return result;
}
```

Now, we can analyze how that function works:

1. It appends the current path to the result
2. It replaces the current path with the parent path
3. It recurses to find a solution for the parent path
4. It appends the complete path to the solution for the parent path

It is always possible to turn a recursive function into a non-recursive function. We just need to manually keep track of already found paths and the current parent path:

```js
function expand(path) {  
  let result = [];
  
  while (path.length > 0) {
    result.push(path);
    path = path.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(expand("/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"));
```

This non-recursive solution works as-is for empty strings without having to check for this base case.

We could even minify it again, which I don't recommend:

```
const res=(s,r=[s])=>{while(s.length)r.push(s=s.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0]);return r};
```

In a practical setting, I would recommend a more generative and more robust approach which, in a first step, extracts all valid path segments from the input. In a second step, you would then build the cumulative paths from those segments.

Using `Array.map()`:

```js
function expand(path, prefix = '') {
  return path.match(/[^\/]+/g).map((segment) => 
    prefix += '/' + segment
  ).reverse();
}

console.log(expand("/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"));
```

Using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
function expand(path, prefix = '') {
  return path.match(/[^\/]+/g).reduce((path, segment) => {
    prefix += '/' + segment;
    path.unshift(prefix);
    return path;
  }, []);
}

console.log(expand("/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
getWords = function(input){
    let results = [];
    input.split("/")
        .filter( (val) => val !== "" )
        .reduce( (acc, val) => {
            acc += '/' + val;
            results.push(acc);
            return acc;
        }, '');
    return results.reverse();
}
```

Rather than recursion (which seems unnecessary) we use `Array.reduce()` to perform the same logic of incrementally building the string.

This might not be optimal from a performance standpoint vs. simply parsing bits of the original input string into a results array but my guess is parsing the original string would be an micro-optimization at the trade-off of code simplicity.

Comment: @le_m Yes it was a typo. I had originally had `results[idx] = acc` but didn't correct it properly :)  Not sure what you mean by getting undefined `acc` is always defined within the closure.

Comment: Yes, indeed you do.

Answer (score 1):

I generally try to avoid regular expressions unless they are super easy to read.
This is how i would do it: a combination of `Array.map`, `Array.slice` and `Array.join`.

Every element in the output array is the concatenation of the first N parts of the complete path.

```js
function expand(path) {
    return path.split('/')
        .filter(x => x)
        .map((x, i, parts) => {
            return '/' + parts.slice(0, i + 1).join('/')
        })
        .reverse()
}

console.log(expand('/this/is/a/test'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on actually doing a code review ;)

**Naming**

- I am a believer in spartan coding, but you may have crossed the line with `j` and `k`, you could find better names than that
- You have anonymous functions, these make stacktraces needlessly complicated

  - Use `function getWords( string ){`
     instead of `getWords = function( string ){`
- Contrary to the previous, for a super simple inline function, I would go further and use the fat arrow syntax
  `a=>a !== ""` instead of `function(a){return a !== ""}`

**Comments**

- Comments should never state the obvious, like here: `// Push the resulting string to the results array`, otherwise I find the code well commented

**JSHint.com**

- Your code fails on some minor items, consider using http://jshint.com/ to perfect your code

**Scope**

- Your code fails on 1 major item, you must declare everything with `var`, `let`, or `const`. I am looking at you, `resultsDisplay` and `input`.

**DOM**

On the whole the following is considered better form

`<input value="bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels" id="input" />
const input = document.getElementsById("input");`
This way your code is more robust (what happens if someone later puts another input field in the HTML code?)

**Counter Proposal**

I cant help myself, but to write a counter proposal as well ;)

```
function getWords( s ){
  let list = s.split("//"), out = [];
  while(list.length>1){
    out.push(list.join("//"));
    list.pop();
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Hi konijin, just a suggestion: your review of OP's original code might fit better to his original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742356/a-better-way-to-get-an-ajustrray-of-strings-separating-a-string-on-n-character-incre

Comment: Nah, codereview.stackexchange.com is where code reviews belong, trust  me ;)

Comment: You would be shocked how many people I've worked with that wouldn't know what `array.push()` does lol.  Other than that you make some good points, even though this was written to work in jsFiddle and not be deployed as production code.  This was more POC code to enable me asking this question, so it was definitely quick and dirty.  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @StephenRios Time to change jobs man ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other good answers but here is my version:

```js
getWords = function( string ){
    let words = string.split("/");
    words = words.filter( function(a){return a !== ""} );

    let results = [];
    while (words.length > 0) {
      results.push('/' + words.join('/') );
      words.pop();
    }

    // Set the results to display
    resultsDisplay.innerHTML = results.toString().replace(/,/g, " -- ");

    // Return the results array
    return results;
}

input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
resultsDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName("results")[0];
input.addEventListener("input", function(){
getWords(input.value)
});
getWords(input.value);
```

```html
<input value="bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels" />
<p class="results"></p>
```